# how to control adding rows if nothing is selected in drop down list without using button in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i would like to know how can i control the adding of rows. rows should'nt be added if there is no selected item in the dropdown list. this is the code.

```
var journalSizeReportingTmpl = 'journalSizeReportingTmpl';
jQuery.template(journalSizeReportingTmpl,
jQuery("#journalSizeReportingTmpl"));

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery(".journalRows").on("change","select.journalMnemonicsDropdown",function(e){
    disableFields(jQuery(this));

});
});

function newJournalRow() {
var id = jQuery('#rowCount').attr("value");
var data = [{fileId: id}];
jQuery.tmpl(journalSizeReportingTmpl, data).insertBefore("tr.lastRow");
id = ++id;
jQuery('#rowCount').attr("value",id);
}
```

//

```
function disableFields(element){
var elementVal = element.attr("value");

var name = element.attr("name");
var id = name.substring(name.indexOf("(")+1,name.indexOf(")"));



if(elementVal== "All"){
    jQuery( "input[name='startVolume("+id+")']" ).attr("disabled",   "disabled");
    jQuery( "input[name='startIssue("+id+")']" ).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    jQuery( "input[name='endVolume("+id+")']" ).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    jQuery( "input[name='endIssue("+id+")']" ).attr("disabled", "disabled");
} else {
    jQuery( "input[name='startVolume("+id+")']" ).removeAttr("disabled");
    jQuery( "input[name='startIssue("+id+")']" ).removeAttr("disabled");
    jQuery( "input[name='endVolume("+id+")']" ).removeAttr("disabled");
    jQuery( "input[name='endIssue("+id+")']" ).removeAttr("disabled");
    newJournalRow();
}
```

Comment: where is the dropdown....

Comment: sorry for that.. this is the additional code

Comment: 'var journalSizeReportingTmpl = 'journalSizeReportingTmpl';
jQuery.template(journalSizeReportingTmpl, jQuery("#journalSizeReportingTmpl"));

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery(".journalRows").on("change","select.journalMnemonicsDropdown",function(e){
  disableFields(jQuery(this));
  
 });
});

function newJournalRow() {
 var id = jQuery('#rowCount').attr("value");
 var data = [{fileId: id}];
 jQuery.tmpl(journalSizeReportingTmpl, data).insertBefore("tr.lastRow");
 id = ++id;
 jQuery('#rowCount').attr("value",id);
}'

Comment: Please edit your post with that code (formatted) as well